# How to find If Java is installed or not using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to fetch if java is installed or not in a system using batch file.
The below code gives me the version if Java is already present. If Java is not present the code fails to execute

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
Set VERSION=%%g
)
```

How can I detect that Java is not installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check java installation from batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951804/how-to-check-java-installation-from-batch-script)

Comment: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` could also be worth a try.

Comment: Can I use the code to parse the error output. The above code gives an error : 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.   Can I somehow parse this error?

Comment: `if "%version%"=="" echo not found`?

Comment: @Stephan : The batch file shuts before executing Set VERSION=%%g

Comment: run it from a `cmd` window to see any errormessages.

Comment: @Stephan : Its not showing error messages

Comment: actually, that's good. (`findstr` didn't find "version", so the `for` loop had nothing to evaluate. So `%version%` is not defined, which you can evaluate with `if "%version%"=="" echo not found` or `if not defined version echo not found`)

Comment: `for %%f in (java.exe) do if "%%~$PATH:f" equ "" echo Java not installed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that any version output you require is on the first line:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "JV="
For /F "Tokens=3" %%A In ('java -version 2^>^&1') Do If Not Defined JV Set "JV=%%~A"
If /I "%JV%"=="not" (Echo Java is not installed) Else Echo Java Version "%JV%"
Pause
```

As a side note, this does not tell you if java is not installed, it tells you whether the java executable is available in the current directory or `%PATH%`. Also note that this uses your stated phrase `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` meaning that this script is probably language dependent.